# Proof for a^n - 1 = 1.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, fake-proofs

I'm reading this book:

https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/The%20Art%20of%20Computer%20Programming%20(vol.%201_%20Fundamental%20Algorithms)%20(3rd%20ed.)%20%5BKnuth%201997-07-17%5D.pdf

And the first exercise is the following:

Let a be any positive number. For all positive integers n, we have a^n - 1 = 1.

Proof.

Base case: n = 1
a^1 - 1 = a^0 = 1.

This is true.

Now, when he tries to prove that a^(n + 1) - 1 = 1, I get confused in the third equality of the formula:

a^(n + 1) - 1 = a^n = ((a^n - 1) * ((a^n - 1)) / ((a^n - 1) - 1) = 1

The idea of the exercise is to prove that the proof is wrong. Now, where did he get the terms ((a^n - 1) * ((a^n - 1)) and ((a^n - 1) - 1) from? Why is he dividing one by the other?

Thank you beforehand for any help.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As written , the expression is $a^n-1$ , not the intented $a^{n-1}$

Comment: $a^{n + 1 - 1} = a^n = a^{n - 1}\times a=a^{n - 1} \times \frac{a^{n - 1}}{a^{n - 2}} = 1\times 1/1=1$.

Comment: The factors are chosen to equal $a^{n}$. That is $a^{n-1}a^{n-1} = a^{2n-2}$. In the denominator $a^{(n-1)-1} = a^{n-2}$. Dividing one by the other $a^{2n-2}/a^{n-2} = a^{n}$. The proof by induction is flawed because it is assumed that the case for $a^{(n-1)-1}$ has been proved, which it has not.